# Flask server sent events (SSE) with uwsgi

Tags: flask, redis, uwsgi, gunicorn, server-sent-events

Basic example from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-SSE

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sse import sse

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["REDIS_URL"] = "redis://localhost"
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

@app.route('/send')
def send_message():
    sse.publish({"message": "Hello!"}, type='greeting')
    return "Message sent!"
```

with:

```
var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('sse.stream') }}");
source.addEventListener('greeting', function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data);
}, false);
source.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    console.log("Failed to connect to event stream.");
}, false);
```

If I use `gunicorn`:

`gunicorn app:app --worker-class gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

messages are successfully received in my template, but if I use `uwsgi`:

`uwsgi --gevent 100 --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi`

with **app.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = app.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

template JavaScript does not receive any message, nor I get any error.

I use redis server on Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make another endpoint to stream whats yours publish:
take a look to this repo https://github.com/jakubroztocil/chat